# Why output undefined?

Tags: javascript

## Question

Here, I created

- an `Owner` object using contructor
- a `Camera` object using contructor

In the 2nd output statement, i was expecting it to show as the 1st statement, but it shows undefined.

This is probably because of the way i've written the `summary()` method as in `this.owner`, `this.make`, etc.

**Note:-** The 1st output statement accesses the variable values from outside of constructor.
But in the 2nd output statement the `summary()` method accesses the variables inside the constructor itself.

Shouldn't the make variable (not arguments) be used in that way?
How to use them inside the object contructor?

Please help me understand this concept.
And also please provide some reference where I could grasp this concept.

**Run test: [Code Snippet @ CodeAcademy Workspace](http://labs.codecademy.com/hif/2#%3aworkspace)**

### Code Snippet

```
//camera object contructor
function Camera(model, make, year, owner)
{
    this.make = make.toString();
    this.model = model.toString();
    this.year = parseInt(year);
    this.owner = function(){
        return (owner.fname + " " + owner.lname).toString();
    }();
    this.summary = function(){
        return this.owner + " bought a " + this.make + " " + this.model + ", released in " + this.year + ".";
    }();
}

//owner object contructor
function Owner(fname, lname){
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
}

//create owner
var niky = new Owner("Niky", "Bauxi");
//create camera for owner
var niky_cam = new Camera("DSLR D3100", "Nikon", 2009, niky);

console.log(niky_cam.owner + " bought a " + niky_cam.make + " " + niky_cam.model + ", released in " + niky_cam.year + ".");
console.log(niky_cam.summary);
```

### Output

```
Niky Bauxi bought a Nikon DSLR D3100, released in 2009.
undefined bought a undefined undefined, released in undefined.
```

### Solution

After considering different answers & comments,

Solution 1: [CodeAcademy workspace](http://labs.codecademy.com/hif/6#%3aworkspace)

Comment: There are many problems in your code, from using toString() and parseInt for no reason, to putting "summary" on every object and not the Camera prototype, your problem is with how _this_ works in JavaScript, it refers to its claled, I'm not sure how niky_cam.summary even works since summary is a function, only .summary() should work...

Comment: if u take a bit more closer look into the `summary()` method, it's a called function like the `owner()` method. And about the `toString()` & `parseInt()`, please ignore them as they are only for exceptions. But that's neither a concern nor a problem for now. The main problem is about the `undefined` output.

Comment: In your code `console.log(niky_cam.summary);` should be `console.log(niky_cam.summary());` , that's not your biggest issue though

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum actually, it shouldn't be `niky_cam.summary()`. That's an error. Because, if i do so, then it's like `"string"()` which is a serious error. It's a `called function`. Please take a closer look. You can see in the 1st statement, i've used `niky_cam.owner` which is also defined same as the `summary()` method and it works perfectly.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you can run `console.log(typeof niky_cam.summary);` in the [CodeAcademy Workspace](http://labs.codecademy.com/hif/3#:workspace) & check the `typeof summary`.

Comment: You're calling `this.owner`, `this.make` and so on in the IIF you're using to make the summary. But inside that IFF, `this` refers to the window object; not the Owner-object you're constructing. I.e. you're trying to use `window.owner`, `window.make` etc., but they don't exist. In any case, this kind of question belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Flambino: That should be an answer.

Comment: @Eric Thanks. Added it as an answer now. Posted the comment while this was still posted over on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and it didn't seem fit to answer it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `this.owner`, `this.make` and so on in the IIF you're using to make the summary. But inside that IIF, `this` refers to the window object; not the Owner-object you're constructing. I.e. you're trying to use `window.owner`, `window.make` etc. in the string, but they don't exist.

Try this

```
function Camera(model, make, year, owner) {
    this.make = make.toString();
    this.model = model.toString();
    this.year = parseInt(year, 10); // ALWAYS supply a radix argument!
    this.owner = (function(){
        return (owner.fname + " " + owner.lname).toString();
    }());
    var that = this;
    this.summary = (function(){
        return that.owner + " bought a " + that.make + " " + that.model + ", released in " + that.year + ".";
    }());
}
```

But the IIFs are both pointless to begin with. You could just as well do this:

```
function Camera(model, make, year, owner) {
    this.make = make.toString();
    this.model = model.toString();
    this.year = parseInt(year, 10);
    this.owner = owner.fname + " " + owner.lname;
    this.summary = this.owner + " bought a " + this.make + " " + this.model + ", released in " + this.year + ".";
}
```

Also, there are better ways to structure all of this (see Benjamin Gruenbaum's comment), but this answers your immediate question.

---

Addendum: You can do IIFs differently using `call` or `apply`, thus passing the context they should be evaluated in

```
function Camera(model, make, year, owner) {
    // ...
    this.summary = (function(){
        return this.owner + " bought a " + this.make + " " + this.model + ", released in " + this.year + ".";
    }).call(this); // explicitly pass the current context to the function
}
```

But, again, all of this is unnecessary in your case.

Comment: what's an IIF? Actually, i'm more into learning theory than real world programming. Just wanted to be conceptually correct. One thing I'm confused about .. Why does the `this` keyword points to `window` object? Am i missing a real concept. Could you please point me to a reference about all this?

Comment: @abhisekp IIF = Immediately-Invoked Function. In other words, a function that's defined and then immediately called, thanks to the `()` right after the closing brace. IIFs are always (I believe) invoked the global object's (i.e. the window's) context, so that's why `this == window`. You can get around that, though; I've added a bit to my answer about it.